# MySQL Insert with lock tables write

Tags: mysql, insert, locking

The task is to upload a price-list of sorts, so quick question before I implement this.

If I want to INSERT say 1000 rows at a time, for say 100,000 the recommendation is:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html

> "If you do very many successive inserts, you could do a LOCK TABLES followed by an UNLOCK TABLES once in a while (each 1,000 rows or so) to permit other threads to access table. This would still result in a nice performance gain."

Obviously while I have the "WRITE LOCK" on the table you can still read the table right?

The reason I ask is that:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html
says:

> Only the session that holds the lock can access the table. No other session **can access it** until the lock is released.

"Can access it"... my gosh, if that is the case them our entire system would freeze up... we simply cant have that... Is this in fact the case, or did they mean "...No other session **can write** to the table until the lock is released."?

Ultimately what I want to be able to do is INSERT 100,000 simple rows of data without impacting the system. I have used:

> INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,0.00),(2,0.00), ...  ..., (999,0.00)

But this often results in no rows added for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you lock a table with `LOCK TABLES ... WRITE` no other thread can read/write that table.

The best approach is to use multi-row insert statements

```
INSERT INTO table (f1,f2,f3....) VALUES
(v1,v2,v3...),
(v1,v2,v3...),
...
```

You will probably need to split your rows into multiple statements with 1-10K rows each (maybe more depending on your max_packet_size and other settings).

MyISAM locks the table if it inserts into empty space somewhere in the middle of the table. If you only do inserts (no deletions) on that table, you should be OK with multiple threads inserting and selecting.

If the table has frequent deletions/updates you should consider switching to InnoDB.

As for "no rows added for some reason"- there is almost certainly an error somewhere in your statement/code. The statement will either insert the rows or return an error.

Comment: Thanks for the info. BTW: the problem of "no rows added for some reason" still exists.... its very strange.